# display details when i click "show"

Tags: php, mysql

hello can somebody give me idea how to do this problem? let say for example i have two table "sales" and "rsales" . and i have this ff data for my tables.

data from sales

```
receipt |  date       | total | 1st_id | last_id |
129999  | 09/26/2013  |  1220 |   1    |   2     |
139999  | 09/27/2013  |  2320 |   3    |   4     |


data from rsales
id | product_name |
1  |   33uf       |
2  |   44uf       |
3  |   7sss       |
4  |   8sss       |
```

and this is my view from my web page when do reports

```
receipt |  date       | total | 1st_id | last_id | + |
129999  | 09/26/2013  |  1220 |   1    |   2     | + |
139999  | 09/27/2013  |  2320 |   3    |   4     | + |
```

so here it is. my problem is that when i click  "+" it will select data from rsales and then display. so let say i cllick "+" where  receipt is 129999 . so the expected output must be something like this.

```
receipt |  date       | total | 1st_id | last_id | + |
129999  | 09/26/2013  |  1220 |   1    |   2     | + |
id      | product_name |
1       |   33uf       |
2       |   44uf       |
139999  | 09/27/2013  |  2320 |   3    |   4     | + |
```

so why it display like this? it is because 1st_id and last_id from sales = id 1 and 2 from rsales. it is hard to explain but i think the example i gave is enough to understand what i want to do. hoping your idea. i really need idea.

Comment: What have you tried? Some example PHP code would be a great place to start.

Comment: i just have a complete running reporton my page. but what i want is that i want to show my page as what is given above as the expected output.

Comment: Are you asking how to write the SQL select? Or how to format table data?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the problem and process you're solving?  it looks like the 1st_id and last_id specify a range of ids on the rsales table.  Do you know what the relationship is supposed to be?  are there any other tables involved?

Comment: its about how to dormat data

Comment: no other table involve only sales and rsales yes 1st_id and last_id is depend on what id is from sales

Comment: What do you mean, format data? Is this a web page? are you looking for php help? javascript/ajax help?

Answer (score 1):

if you have it set up the way I think you have it set up you'll need two queries:

```
SELECT 1st_id, last_id FROM sales WHERE receipt=?
```

and then

```
SELECT Id, product_name FROM rsales WHERE Id>=[variable from 1st_id] AND Id<=[variable from last_id];
```

if I were doing it I would have set up 3 tables

a sales_rsales with 3 fields, id, sales_receipt, rsales_id.Get rid of 1st_id and last_id  use that to track the products per receipt then the SQL will be easy:

```
SELECT rsales.Id, rsales.product
  FROM rsales JOIN sales_rsales ON rsales.Id=sales_rsales.rsales_id
  JOIN sales ON sales.receipt=sales_rsales.sales_receipt
  WHERE sales.receipt=?
```

Comment: When adding code to your questions or answers, indent by four spaces for proper formatting, or select it and use the `{}` button to do it automatically.